# How many three digit numbers are with certain constraints

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:
How many different three-digit numbers can be made with $3$ fours, $4$ twos and
$2$ threes?

Answer:
Let $c$ be the count we seek.
I am going to start by enumerating the cases using just fours and twos. Here is my list:
$$ 222 \, , \, 224 \, , \, 242 \, , \, 244 \,  $$
$$ 422 \, , \, 424 \, , \, 442 \, , \, 444 \,  $$
Hence we have $8$ items on our list so far. Now we can add terms with one three at the
end.
$$ 223 \, , \, 423 \, , \, 243 \, , \, 443$$
We have four of them. So if you let the $3$ be placed anywhere, that gives you
$12$ more terms. Now for the terms that contain $2$ threes.
In this case, there can only by one non-three digit. There are three spots for it. In
addition, the non-three digit can be either a $3$ or a $2$. Hence we have:
$$ c = 8 + 4(3) + 3(2) = 8 + 12 + 6 $$
$$ c = 26 $$
My answer matches the book's answer. However, my reasoning does not seem right to me. I am not sure why. Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach -

As we have to make three digit numbers, if there were *three* $3$'s then each digit could be chosen from $2, 3, 4$ and that would give $3^3 = 27$ numbers. But this also includes number $333$, which has three $3$'s. As we have only two $3$'s, we can make $27 - 1 = 26$ numbers.

Comment: Shades of the "17 Camels" problem....